# How does a graphic designer design a webpage?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

This is a really stupid question, I know. I took a graphic design class some years ago and we designed our website in Photoshop and then sliced it.
I have a feeling graphic designers don't do that anymore.
Update me, please? :)
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17928/what-is-the-exact-role-relationship-of-photoshop-in-web-design (Yes, more than 3 years old, but more relevant than slicing a Photoshop document)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the exact role/relationship of photoshop in web design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17928/what-is-the-exact-role-relationship-of-photoshop-in-web-design)

Comment: @Scott I agree that this is a possible duplicate at first glance, but I think the question is more asking **"is using Photoshop for web design obsolete now?"** as OP said **"I have a feeling graphic designers don't do that anymore. Update me, please? :)"** I believe this is an appropriate question due to how rapidly webpage development has changed in just 3 years. It gives an opportunity to say what ways Photoshop can be used in web development, whether it is still a good idea, pros/cons, alternatives/more common methods of creating a website.

Comment: @LateralTerminal you are free to interpret the question however you'd like. I interpret it as pretty much a duplicate.

Comment: At the high-end of the web design, Photoshop has near-universally been shunned as a problematic way of site layout throughout web design history and this hasn't changed. That doesn't mean lots of companies didn't do so and it wasn't taught in courses, which also hasn't changed. What has changed is that a lot of people who are happy to use Photoshop for designing websites have also taken up other image software that may have more tools orientated to layout design - such as Sketch, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of different ways to make a website. There's no correct way to make a website. There are countless services and different approaches to making a website.

## It's going to depend on what your company specializes in

- What programs they already bought
- What they plan to do with the website
- What type of computers will be using the website. Ex: desktop only, mobile only, both, or neither?
- Is it going to be something used internally only?
- If it's not going to be used internally, then what type of customers are they anticipating?
- How important is compatibility to older operating systems and browsers?

#### If you are freelance here are some suggestions and things to consider when making a website in 2017

You get to make your own rules unless your customer tells you specifically what they want.

- ***For free:*** If I'm making a responsive website I like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for compatibility between different device screen sizes. You can use elements you made in Photoshop or SVG elements. You can do basically anything with bootstrap with HTML and CSS. You have to be comfortable using Notepad to write the website or something free like https://www.sublimetext.com/ which is just an HTML editor that makes it easier to understand.
- ***Have Adobe:*** You can also consider Muse which is more for GUI comfortable users and also makes responsive websites like bootstrap and utilizes Photoshop in many ways. [Info on Muse and Photoshop.](https://helpx.adobe.com/muse/how-to/muse-place-layered-psd-file.html) Muse lets you use Photoshop for various things for example to make buttons change to a different picture when you hover over them.

  Also, Adobe's Dreamweaver is an
  option too if you want less hand holding as it is mostly an HTML editor. Adobe has a video to help you decide whether you should use Dreamweaver or Muse

However, if you are trying to make a light website ***you would not use
   Photoshop for everything.*** You would create many assets as SVG in Illustrator or another free vector program if
   possible, because it will load a lot faster and look a lot cleaner
   when scaled to different sizes. [More info svg.](https://svgontheweb.com/)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to make website elements in say, Illustrator or Photoshop and then send it to a programmer, who will "connect" everything together? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's basically how it works. You could probably do it yourself in Adobe Muse if you wanted. It's supposed to make it easier for people who don't know anything about programming. If you look at a few YouTube tutorial videos and Adobe videos on their website it will be pretty easy.

Comment: @HazelnutSpread Yes

Comment: @HazelnutSpread At this site we upvote to say thank you instead of saying it in the comments. That way people know it's helpful. If you think it's the correct answer you can mark it as a correct answer. I don't want to pressure you to accept this as the correct answer. If you aren't sure yet you can wait for someone else to make an answer select what you think is best.

Comment: So at stack exchange we encourage memebers to say thank you by either upvote or select it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I build (a lot of) websits for designers. Most of them work in InDesign and deliver high quality print PDF files and an InDesign package. I think that is a pretty normal workflow nowadays. This also means I get to decide on most of the responsive stuff.

Hope it helps you!